# redhat 6 | how-to install libpcap-devel

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, yum, rpm

the server is running:

```
# cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-023.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013
```

and it seems that the `libpcap-devel` is not available,
and i cannot find the package in any repository.

```
# yum search libpcap-devel
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository epel-debuginfo is listed more than once in the configuration
Warning: No matches found for: libpcap-devel
No Matches found
```

The solution seems to be here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/57913
but I do not have access ..

Could you please advise on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

Spelling out Michael's answer:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
sudo yum install libpcap-devel
sudo yum-config-manager --disable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
```

Or you can edit /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo:

```
[rhel-6-server-optional-rpms]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Server - Optional (RPMs)
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/6/$releasever/$basearch/optional/os
enabled = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

libpcap-devel is in the RHEL optional channel, which you need to [enable](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/392003) on your system.

And if you don't have access to RHEL documentation, you need to talk to whoever is in charge of that in your company to get your Red Hat account authorized for access.